# GROUP BY in SQL is not giving correct result

Tags: sql

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62003/3

In above fiddle, there are 4 different subid and query is GROUP BY on subid. But it's giving 0 for all subid after GROUP BY.

Please advise on why it is not giving 10 and 20 as result for 2 subid? What wrong I am doing in query? Please let me know.

Comment: Include subid in the select list, and the result will be much easier to understand!

Comment: is `mpkid` is unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `GROUP BY` you get result for each group. If you want to skip them use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT SUM(shippingvalue) AS shippingvalue
FROM t_product_purchase 
WHERE mpkid=5 
GROUP BY subid
HAVING shippingvalue <> 0;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62003/5/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════════════╗
║ shippingvalue ║
╠═══════════════╣
║            10 ║
║            20 ║
╚═══════════════╝
```

If you want `subid` in resultset use:

```
SELECT subid, SUM(shippingvalue) AS shippingvalue
FROM t_product_purchase 
WHERE mpkid=5 
GROUP BY subid
HAVING shippingvalue <> 0
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62003/10/0)**</kbd>